# Объясните данный цикл for в c++

Tags: visual-c++, циклы

Почему в данном цикле у меня выводится 0, а не 100?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сумма всех целых чисел от -100 до +100 равна чему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот-вот. Именно 0.

И еще - не нужно этих кричащих картинок. Текст куда скромнее, а главное - **удобнее**: его даже можно перенести в свой компилятор и посмотреть, что и как. Это намек на будущее...

Comment: Но мы же присваиваем sum значение i после добавление i 1. Получается sum = -99, -98 -97 и и так до 100???

Comment: Вы не присваиваете значение `i`. `sum += i` (обратите внимание на `+=`) - это сокращенная запись для `sum = sum + i`.